# How can I find the import name for a module in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I am using Python 3 with Anaconda as an installer and Jupyter as my day to day programming environment. For many modules (for example numpy) the module can be imported by using the package name I see when I use "conda list" ie:

```
import numpy
```

However for some other packages "conda list" gives a name (eg scikit-learn) which is not reflected in its corresponding import name. For example for scikit-learn I have to use:

```
import sklearn
```

What is the best method to determine the correct import name for a new package I have installed?

I looked through https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path but it has left me none the wiser

Comment: I would suggest the package documentation (online), since that will also show you the standard way of importing, and common imports. E.g., `import numpy as np` is just as common as `import numpy`. Thus, you get the bonus of the (package) idiom.

Comment: also, if you type the first letters and then use the `tab` key, `Jupyter` will offer you matching possible completions of the beginning word.

Comment: Going to where you have your package installed, e.g. `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`, there'll be a distinfo like `scikit_learn-0.19.1.dist-info`. In here, a `RECORD` text file will reveal that all references lead to a `sklearn` folder. But reading the documentation is probably faster.

Comment: Thank you for these hints, very useful. @ivo: your suggestion is nice and simple, but does not help in some cases (scikit-learn is a good example) because the import name differs from the package install name so early on (second character for scikit-learn)